# pthread_mutex_t struct: What does lock stand for?

Tags: locking, pthreads, posix, mutex, mutual-exclusion

I am looking at the pthread_mutex_t structure in the pthreadtypes.h file. What does the "__lock" stand for? Is it like a lock number assigned to the mutex?

```
typedef union
{
  struct __pthread_mutex_s
  {
     int __lock;
     unsigned int __count;
     int __owner;
     #if __WORDSIZE == 64
     unsigned int __nusers;
     #endif
    /* KIND must stay at this position in the structure to maintain
     binary compatibility.  */
     int __kind;
     #if __WORDSIZE == 64
     int __spins;
     __pthread_list_t __list;
     # define __PTHREAD_MUTEX_HAVE_PREV 1
     #else
     unsigned int __nusers;
     __extension__ union
    {
      int __spins;
      __pthread_slist_t __list;
    };
    #endif
  } __data;
 char __size[__SIZEOF_PTHREAD_MUTEX_T];
 long int __align;
```

} pthread_mutex_t;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__lock` member of `struct __pthread_mutex_s` `__data` is used as a futex object on Linux.  Many of the following details may differ depending on the architecture you're looking at:

See the `pthread_mutex_lock.c` code for the high level locking function for pthread mutexes - `__pthread_mutex_lock()`, which generally will end up calling `LLL_MUTEX_LOCK()` and the  definitions of `LLL_MUTEX_LOCK()` and friends, which end up calling `lll_lock()`, etc., in `lowlevellock.h`.

The `lll_lock()` macro in turn calls `__lll_lock_wait_private()`, which calls `lll_futex_wait()`, which makes the `sys_futex` system call.